# Spark 2.1.1 Exception in cloudera vm | Yarn applicarion has already ended

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have updated the spark version from 1.6 to 2.1.1 . I have updated java version and scala version . But when I start spark-shell .I get following error when starting spark-shell . Please help me with this .I am new to spark . Please post some step to correct this error . The Error is displayed when starting spark-shell.

```
 18/10/16 11:59:37 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
 org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File
```

/user/cloudera/.sparkStaging/application_1539716150434_0001/**spark_conf**.zip could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2222)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2220)

```
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1469)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1400)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1532)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1349)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:588)
```

18/10/16 11:59:37 ERROR spark.SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/cloudera/.sparkStaging/application_1539716150434_0001/**spark_conf**.zip could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2222)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2220)

```
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1469)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1400)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1532)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1349)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:588)
```

18/10/16 11:59:37 WARN cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
18/10/16 11:59:37 ERROR util.Utils: Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleClient.close(ExternalShuffleClient.java:152)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.stop(BlockManager.scala:1407)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$11.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1849)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1848)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:587)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:868)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$6.apply(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:860)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:96)
    at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.(:15)
    at $line3.$read$$iw.(:42)
    at $line3.$read.(:44)
    at $line3.$read$.(:48)
    at $line3.$read$.()
    at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(:7)
    at $line3.$eval$.$print(:6)
    at $line3.$eval.$print()
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:105)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: File /user/cloudera/.sparkStaging/application_1539716150434_0001/**spark_conf**.zip could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3440)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:686)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.addBlock(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:217)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:506)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2222)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1917)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2220)

at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1469)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1400)
  at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.addBlock(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:399)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
  at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.addBlock(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1532)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1349)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:588)
:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
          ^

Comment: Can you set SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 on terminal before running spark shell?

Comment: What do you mean upgraded? From cloudera manager? Cloudera's spark2? Did you try spark2-shell

Comment: @RamdevSharma 

I am not able to access the spark shell . I have updated SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION .


I have updated the version of spark from 1.6 to 2.1.1 in cloudera vm . 
I am posting the error again please help me in fixing this error.